# Javascript key event prohibits click event temporarily

Tags: javascript, events, click, keypress, disabled-control

I am having a weird little issue which seems to be restricted to Windows(Edge, IE, Firefox, Chrome & Opera). I have tested it under Windows 10 x64. After a key{up,down,press} event, the click event seems to be temporarily disabled. Anyone knows how I can fix this?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b4s1pqe7/1/

```
// add event listener to table
function callEvent(e) {
    console.log(Date.now() + " " + e.type);
}

document.addEventListener("click", callEvent);
document.addEventListener("keyup", callEvent);
```

How To:

- Open your console log in your browser
- Press a key on your keyboard
- Start clicking furiously in the HTML part of the Fiddle.
- Note that click events temporarily do not show up

When I open it in a browser under Linux (tested with Firefox) the event is not temporarily disabled. @itsgoingdown tested it under Windows 7 SP 1 with Chrome and it also does not have this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is odd! Could you let me know which OS and browser you are using?

Comment: Windows 7 sp1,  Chrome Version 49.0.2623.112 m

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am running Windows 10 myself and I do have the issue in the same version of Chrome. Could someone else who also runs Windows 10 try it please? Would be really helpful!